# Using AllowGroups And Restrict by ip address

Tags: linux, security, openssh

i'm trying to manage access for ssh with AllowGroups, and it's working fine. Now i would like to restrict access to some groups only if they connect from a specific host, with AllowUsers it works like user@192.168.0.1 but in AllowGroups isn't working.

Like:

AllowGroups itstaff securitystaff@192.168.0.1

I have tried using Match Address and AllowGroups inside but it seems that AllowGroups is not allowed within a Match Block.

Match Address "192.168.0.1"
  AllowGroups securitystaff

sshd service fails to start and i get the message "Directive AllowGroups is not allowed within a match block.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/326100/openssh-allowgroups-group-from-specific-host Please see the answers posted there.

Comment: The general rule of thumb for authentication is for the program to use PAM and only implement access controls that pertain to the application's purpose or internal function. For generally useful things like locking groups down to subnets, chances are that there exists a PAM module to do whatever specific thing you want. Most daemons don't re-invent the wheel and will just tell you to use the relevant PAM module(s) for setting the specific policy that you're after. In this case `pam_access` is what you're after.

Comment: Posted that as a comment since there's no real way to answer this question as it's written since it's neither possible or advisable.

Comment: Thanks, from what i've read that means that i should put something like:

Comment: AllowGroups itstaff securitystaff
 (in sshd_conf) 
and
+ : securitystaff  : 192.168.0.1
- :  securitystaff : ALL 
 (in /etc/security/access.conf)
Is it necessary that i put itstaff too on access.conf?

Answer (score 1):

I've experimented many times and finally found how to make it work.

First, *outside* any match block set the groups you always want to allow access from:

`AllowGroups staff`

Then inside a match block restrict another group's access by IP address/network:

```
Match Group group1 Address 10.0.0.0/24
    AllowGroups *
```

AllowGroups * is important. AllowUsers * doesn't work here.

This results in allowing group staff from anywhere, and group group1 only from 10.0.0.0/24.
Enjoy.